# How to access videos in Facebook livemap programmatically?

Tags: python, facebook-live-api

Is there a Facebook API call to retrieve all or a subset of the current live videos with the relative metadata, such as location, user who is streaming, time at stream?
The implementation could be in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no such API at this time.

Comment: is there (and it is allowed) a way to do it via scraping using a tool such as Scrapy for example?